# Login account before sending e-mail

Tags: c#, winforms, email, authentication

I am developing an application for sending email using SmtpClient, works very well, but I have a question about user authentication, because the codes that I saw, you can only know if e-mail and password are correct when e-mail is sent.

Is there any way to do this authentication before. I am using this piece as an example:

```
public void SendMessage()
{
    MailMessage mensagem = new MailMessage();
    mensagem.From = new MailAddress(email);
    mensagem.To.Add(txtto.Text);
    mensagem.Subject = txtsubject.Text;
    mensagem.Body = richMessage.Text;

    SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();

    if (Form1.servidor.Equals("hotmail.com"))
    {
        smtp.Host = "smtp.live.com";
        smtp.Port = 25;
        smtp.EnableSsl = true;
    }

    smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(email, Form1.password);

    //only in this line is actually verified the existence of the user + password
    smtp.Send(mensagem);    
}
```

I don't wanna need send message to know if user+password is correct. Anybody knows someway, maybe another namespace...

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could use impersonation, e.g. with [this the small impersonation class](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10090/A-small-C-Class-for-impersonating-a-User) to try to log in a Windows user.

I.e. place the following `using` block around your code to run under the other user account:

```
using ( new Impersonator( "myUsername", "myDomainname", "myPassword" ) )
{
   ...

   <code that executes under the new context>

   ...
}
```

You could `try...catch` around the using block to check for wrong password, or, better, use the function inside the `Impersonator`'s source to login and check the result, i.e. without catching (performance).

Comment: but i don't wanna log on Windows user, i wanna log on e-mail. You know another way?